# Tkinter in python - not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I wanted to use tkinter in python 2.7, but it says, it is not found. Neither I can install it using pip install. How to install it ?

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tkinter

>>> import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Tkinter
>>>



pip install tkinter
Collecting tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter


 pip install Tkinter
Collecting Tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Tkinter
```

Comment: Did you get any warnings about your pip version?

Comment: you can't install tkinter with pip

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the  [`python-tk`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python-tk)  package:

```
apt install python-tk
```